# Examples of contraction homeomorphism

Tags: dynamical-systems, contraction-operator

Let $X$ be a compact metric space with metric $d$ and let $f:X \rightarrow X$ be a homeomorphism. We say that $f$ is a contraction, if there exists $0 < c < 1$ such that $d(f(x), f(y)) \leq c d(x, y) $ for every pair of distinct points $x, y\in X$. 
Will you please help me to find some examples of such maps (Please ignore matrix based maps).

Answer (score 4):

There is no such map. Let $x,x'\in X$ such that $d(x,x')$ is maximal. Take, if possible, $y,y'\in X$ such that $f(y)=x$ and that $f(y')=x'$. Then$$d(x,x')=d\bigl(f(y),f(y')\bigr)\leqslant cd(y,y')<d(y,y')\leqslant d(x,x')$$which is impossible. So, no such $y,y'\in X$ exist and therefore $f$ is *not* a homeomorphism.

Comment: So this is only impossible because $X$ is compact?

Comment: @James_T If $X$ is non-compact, there are examples of homeomorphisms for which the property described in the question holds. For instance, if $X=\Bbb R$, and $d$ is the usual distance, then you can take $f(x)=\frac x2$.