# Examples of Surjective Contractions on Reals

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, contraction-operator

After reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042921/examples-of-contraction-homeomorphism) where OP assumes compactness, I wonder the following.  Are there examples of $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which are continuous surjections and are also contractions, in the sense that:
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y| \mbox{ if $x\neq y$}?
$$

**Edit:** I'm looking especially for non-linear examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as written no - take $x=y$. But if we modify the rule to $$x\not=y\implies \vert x-y\vert>\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert$$then the answer is **yes**. For example, consider the function $$x\mapsto {1\over 2}x.$$ This has the effect of shrinking all distances by a factor of $2$.

Comment: Right, but what would be examples of non-linear such functions?