# Example of Non-Affine Lipschitz Contractions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, lipschitz-functions

This is a follow-up to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785227/examples-of-surjective-contractions-on-reals), to correct an impression on my behalf.  What are examples of continuous, non-affine, contractions on $\mathbb{R}$.  That is, maps $f$ satisfying
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|< |x-y| \mbox{ if $x\neq y$}
$$
which are not of the form $f(x)=Ax +b$ and are continuous and surjective?

Comment: Have you tried to glue functions together which have the property? For example, you can glue to different affine functions together at some $x_0$. An other example could be the $\log$. If you stretch it enough, it becomes a contraction for $x>1$ and at this point you can glue either some sort of shifted $\log(-x)$ or an affine function.

Comment: @MushuNrek  Yes, that's what I ended up doing actually.